# Find a value in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript object which looks like this:

```
tabAndFieldLink: {
    'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'],
    'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27'],
    'key3': ['value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34'],
    'key4': ['value41', 'value42'],
}
```

**What I want**

I have the value `value22` and I want to get it's key i.e. `key2`.

**What I tried**

```
for (err in errorArray) {
    //err contain the value i.e. value22
    var resultObject = search(err, tabAndFieldLink);
    console.log("The result is :", resultObject);
}

function search(nameKey, myArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].indexOf(nameKey) !== -1) {
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But it is printing `"The result is :", undefined`. How can I get the key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should  use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to  iterates over the enumerable properties of object `tabAndFieldLink` and as you need `key` return it.

```
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].indexOf(nameKey) !== -1) {
        return key;
    }
}
```

```js
var tabAndFieldLink = {
  'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'],
  'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27'],
  'key3': ['value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34'],
  'key4': ['value41', 'value42'],
}

//err contain the value i.e. value22
var err = 'value22';
var resultObject = search(err, tabAndFieldLink);
console.log("The result is :", resultObject);

function search(nameKey, obj) {
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].indexOf(nameKey) !== -1) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many inbuilt functional behavior present in the Javascript, which can be used in cases like this.

Here is the code using  arrays `filter`

```
var tabAndFieldLink =  {
    'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'],
    'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27'],
    'key3': ['value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34'],
    'key4': ['value41', 'value42'],
}


function getKey(checkValue) {
    for (key in tabAndFieldLink) {
        var newArr = tabAndFieldLink[key].filter(function(value){
            return value == 'value22';
        });
        if(newArr.length > 0) {
            console.log("Found......", key);
            return key;
            }
    }
}

console.log(getKey('value22'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), if the value is in the array with a specific key, then return that key.

```js
function  getKey(object, value) {
    var key;
    Object.keys(object).some(function (k) {
        if (object[k].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            key = k;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return key;
}

var object = { key1: ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'], key2: [ 'value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27'], key3: ['value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34'], key4: ['value41', 'value42'] },
    find = 'value22',
    key = getKey(object, find);

console.log(key);
```

ES6 with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
function  getKey(object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(k => object[k].includes(value));
}


var object = { key1: ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'], key2: [ 'value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27'], key3: ['value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34'], key4: ['value41', 'value42'] },
    find = 'value22',
    key = getKey(object, find);

console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tabAndFieldLink structure is a Hash containing key value pairs.  Each value is an Array.

Navigate the structure as per the snippet below.

```js
var tabAndFieldLink = {
  'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'],
  'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27'],
  'key3': ['value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34'],
  'key4': ['value41', 'value42'],
};

var resultObject = search("value22", tabAndFieldLink);
console.log("The result is :", resultObject);

function search(nameKey, myHash) {
  for (var key in myHash) {
    if (myHash[key].indexOf(nameKey) !== -1) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use find and Object Keys function

```js
var data = {
    'key1': ['value11', 'value22', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'],
    'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27'],
    'key3': ['value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34'],
    'key4': ['value41', 'value42'],
}

function findValue(search){
var result = []
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
 var r = data[key].find(function(value){ 
           return value === search 
        })
 r && result.push(key)
})
console.log(result)
}

findValue("value22")
```