# Access object in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class ResistorColor {
  private colors: string[]
    
  public colorValues = {
    black: 0,
    brown: 1,
    red: 2,
    orange: 3,
    yellow: 4,
    green: 5,
    blue: 6,
    violet: 7,
    grey: 8,
    white: 9
  }

  constructor(colors: string[]) {
    
    if( colors.length > 2)
    {
      for( key in this.colorValues)
      {
        if (this.colorValues[key].indexOf(colors[0]) !== -1) 
        {
          return key;
        }
      }
    }

    this.colors = colors
    
  }
}
```

Idea is to find whether the color that has been input by the user is present in the object `colorValues` or not.

I referred to this: [Find a value in a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673303/find-a-value-in-a-javascript-object)

I am getting the error of `cannot find name key`. I am using a Typescript, online editor.

Please explain to me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Not related to the question, instead of `a.indexOf(v) !== -1` use [`a.includes(v)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: @axiac Thank you. I will upvote if you write that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cannot find name key` error is answered by @MrCodingB

A nicer way to write this:

```
class ResistorColor {
  private colors: string[]
    
  public colorValues = {
    black: 0,
    brown: 1,
    red: 2,
    orange: 3,
    yellow: 4,
    green: 5,
    blue: 6,
    violet: 7,
    grey: 8,
    white: 9
  }

  constructor(colors: string[]) {
    
    const colorValues = Object.keys(this.colorValues);
    // colorValues is ["black", "brown", "red", ...]

    const isValid = colors.every(c => colorValues.includes(c));
    // `every` is used to tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function, 
    // in this case, we check whether each value exists in `colorValues`

    if (isValid) {
      this.colors = colors
    } else {
      throw new Error("Invalid Color(s)");
    }
  }
}

const resistorColor = new ResistorColor(["black", "brown"]); // correct
console.log("resistorColor has correct color");

const resistorColor2 = new ResistorColor(["black", "brown", "gold"]); // throws error
console.log("resistorColor2 has correct color");
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmECWEAuB7ATgYXSL0A3gFDTQAOmSAbmKvNMHlhAFzRpUB2A5gNoBdUmWjDyAVwBGIJMEbNMANTAhxiaAF4iwstLDAA1uwAMAGh3RJmdAHcu7AIzmR0TPAAm7AEzORWMLzw7ADMvmQAnvAg+DbsACxh0Dxu8PbQAKyJ0mrsAGyJ1Eh48KjsAOyJyfDh7AAciTYAFkj07ACcwgC+xMJMXJziwBiYABRM+JhsHKjc-AIAlNouFn1o8hPKqupaAPKSAFbwQwB0BtUQI6jNEMfjWJtqEPMA3Cvo-ajQKJtI7prrLGO8Go8Ew4TGmgAfAClCpHsckFxQOJ3IgxvMXj0XEgAGbQEbfFS-RYkFxkK4oW4KGBaO6TCydaBRCAMUlkq7WGzQLjwLkAUUw1lGACIAJJcWgyP64CbCzEubpkbrdYirT5uZBoLAyghaHlchCa4Y60Z8YV6QzC0zQc2crjChbPaAAemd8kFR1QqveEGKx3wPBGwo1KGNCmgjUg7rcQxhcte3o+rkQoe1Ci8-31cBTWpwChGZotBitNqstnt1uFPDw7gdLxdbo5thgoKFid9IHg-vQgeDObDEwzkZgTA9sbp8aAA)

---

It's also possible to print out the incorrect colors value by using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
class ResistorColor {
  private colors: string[]
    
  public colorValues = {
    black: 0,
    brown: 1,
    red: 2,
    orange: 3,
    yellow: 4,
    green: 5,
    blue: 6,
    violet: 7,
    grey: 8,
    white: 9
  }

  constructor(colors: string[]) {
    
    const colorValues = Object.keys(this.colorValues);
    const invalidColors = colors.filter(c => !colorValues.includes(c));

    if (invalidColors.length === 0) {
      this.colors = colors
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Invalid Color -> ${invalidColors.join(", ")}`);
    }
  }
}

const resistorColor = new ResistorColor(["black", "brown"]); // correct
console.log("resistorColor has correct color");

const resistorColor2 = new ResistorColor(["black", "brown", "gold", "foo"]); // throws error "Invalid Color -> gold, foo"
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmECWEAuB7ATgYXSL0A3gFDTQAOmSAbmKvNMHlhAFzRpUB2A5gNoBdUmWjDyAVwBGIJMEbNMANTAhxiaAF4iwstLDAA1uwAMAGh3RJmdAHcu7AIzmR0TPAAm7AEzORWMLzw7ADMvmQAnvAg+DbsACxh0Dxu8PbQAKyJ0mrsAGyJ1Eh48KjsAOyJyfDh7AAciTYAFkj07ACcwgC+xMJMXJziwBiYABRM+JhsHKjc-AIAlNouFn1o8hPKqupaAPKSAFbwQwB0BtUQI6jNEMfjWJtqEPMA3Cvo-ajQSFy0Mu64ExgWjuk2OADMkCB6KM5BoAHzQACEIIeiGO31A4nciDG8xePRcSDB0BG31+SH+ChuIFSPCumg0WmMixILjIVxQtypmnWLAsnWgUQgDFZbKu1hs0C48ElAFFMNZRgADACSPxUFOgAIIAFoEQASQhkjWUwHHfbob4jABEpmg1vmnSV+Jc3TI3W6xFWnzcyDQWG1mB50slCD9w0DIz41r0hlt9qsti41oWz2gAHp0-IFUdUF73hBisd8Dwbb6UBGFNBGpBs24hrzMA7XvmPq5EBWAwovMGZXAO-6cAoozHwHG7TGJcmJzw8O549aweh0CmXhms+LbDB4AqsK3CzTi+hS9by4PAz2azAmDmGyDm0A)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Look at @Owl 's answer, it fixes the other problems in your code too.

In your loop the variable `key` is not defined. You'd have to write it like this:

```js
for (const key in this.colorValues) {
  ...
}
```

Although I wouldn't use a for-in loop, since objects have their own prototype properties, which you would also receive in a for-in loop. A better solution would be this:

```js
for (const key of Object.keys(this.colorValues) {
  ...
}
```

But since you don't need the keys and just use them to retreive the values in the colorValues object, you could also use this:

```js
for (const color of Object.values(this.colorValues) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: alright. Is there any other way of writing it?

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Some of the errors that you are trying to prevent at run-time can be avoided at compile-time with stricter types.  You can create a type that only allows specific [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) color names and you can also enforce a minimum length on the `colors` array using [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).

It looks like `this.colorValues` might just be an [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums)?

```
enum COLOR_VALUES {
    black = 0,
    brown = 1,
    red = 2,
    orange = 3,
    yellow = 4,
    green = 5,
    blue = 6,
    violet = 7,
    grey = 8,
    white = 9
}

type ColorNames = keyof typeof COLOR_VALUES;

class ResistorColor {

    // can have two or more colors
    constructor(private colors: [ColorNames, ColorNames, ...ColorNames[]]) {
    }
}
```

Now you can only call the constructor with valid arguments.

```
const a = new ResistorColor(["black", "blue"]); // ok
const b = new ResistorColor(["black", "blue", "red"]); // ok
const c = new ResistorColor(["black"]); // error: Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2.
const d = new ResistorColor(["white", "cyan"]); // error: Type '"cyan"' is not assignable to type
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0LeN)

If `this.colorValues` is an instance variable I would create the initial value outside of the class so that we can use `typeof`.

```
const initialValues = {
    black: 0,
    brown: 1,
    red: 2,
    orange: 3,
    yellow: 4,
    green: 5,
    blue: 6,
    violet: 7,
    grey: 8,
    white: 9
  }

type ColorNames = keyof typeof initialValues;

class ResistorColor {

    public colorValues = initialValues;

    // can have two or more colors
    constructor(private colors: [ColorNames, ColorNames, ...ColorNames[]]) {
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wRpzXm)

Comment: Very much thankful for the helpful answer.