# 'includes()' is for string, not for array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

> Object.keys()
> Returns an array containing the names of all of the given object's own enumerable string properties.

This says that 'includes' works on strings:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Then why is the following statement valid in the code shown in this SO thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66758849/462608

```
const colorValues = Object.keys(this.colorValues);
const invalidColors = colors.filter(c => !colorValues.includes(c));
```

Comment: `includes` works on arrays too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on `w3schools` for information. The MDN developer guides are a much better resource.

Comment: You were checking the string documentation on w3schools, the array one also has its own `includes`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It exists on both prototypes: `String.prototype.includes` and `Array.prototype.includes`.

`String.prototype.includes` checks if the string contains the passed substring.

`Array.prototype.includes` checks if the array contains a particular value (with the SameValueZero algorithm).

Somewhat confusingly, they use the exact same name, but the logic employed is similar.